# Vercel cli build fails with error "Type error: Cannot find module 'Formik' or its corresponding type declarations."

Tags: typescript, formik, vercel

Still kinda new to TypeScript and only a day and a half trying to get Vercel to work.  I'm trying to deploy via the Vercel cli.  I'm logged in, verified by looking at the failed build logs in Vercel's dashboard. When I run "npx vercel" (I'm on Windows) the error I'm getting is:

> Build error: "Type error: Cannot find module 'Formik' or its
> corresponding type declarations."

I've tried:

1. Changing in tsconfig.json the compilerOptions.target from "ESNext" to "ES2015" and "ES5". Vercel changes it on build to "ESNext".
2. "vercel --dev" builds successfully locally.
3. "vercel --prod" fails at the same point.
4. Referenced "Formik" as "formik".
5. Removing exclusion of node_modules in tsconfig.json. Vercel changes it so that node_modules is excluded anyways.
6. Override Vercel build settings so Build Command uses "yarn build". Also tried "next build".
7. Override Vercel build settings so Install Command uses "yarn install".
8. Change the node.js version from 14.x to 12.x in Vercel's settings
9. Dug through several Google searches, Vercel docs, Issues on Vercel's Github, and here on SO.
10. "npx yarn build" is successful locally.

I have a hunch that it might be a Windows vs Linux issue (upper vs lower case filenames), but can't confirm.  I'm on Windows 10 and Vercel (per their build logs) is Linux. But Formik is a package that I've installed via command line and I'd find it odd that would need to be changed manually.

Another thing that's odd to me is that there is no node_modules folder in the source files output from Vercel.  I would expect something to be there after it runs yarn install.

## Files and logs:

Error thrown from the second line of ./src/components/InputField.tsx:

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import { Field } from "Formik";
...
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",    
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "src/utils/createWithApollo.js"  ]
    ,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-chakra-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "gen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.1.3",
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.3.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.1.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "framer-motion": "^3.3.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-apollo": "^5.0.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "1.20.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.20.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "1.17.14",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

Sample log from failed build:

```
20:42:15.582    Retrieving list of deployment files...
20:42:20.745    Downloading 61 deployment files...
20:42:21.224    Analyzing source code...
20:42:22.920    Installing build runtime...
20:42:27.164    Build runtime installed: 4.245s
20:42:31.022    Looking up build cache...
20:42:32.091    Build cache not found
20:42:33.365    Installing dependencies...
20:42:33.706    yarn install v1.22.10
20:42:33.770    [1/4] Resolving packages...
20:42:34.081    [2/4] Fetching packages...
20:42:49.164    info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
20:42:49.164    info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
20:42:49.176    [3/4] Linking dependencies...
20:42:49.178    warning " > @apollo/client@3.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "subscriptions-transport-ws@^0.9.0".
20:42:49.179    warning " > @chakra-ui/icons@1.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".
20:42:49.179    warning "@chakra-ui/icons > @chakra-ui/icon@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".
20:42:49.183    warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/modal > react-remove-scroll@2.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
20:42:49.183    warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/modal > @chakra-ui/focus-lock > react-focus-lock@2.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
20:42:49.185    warning "@emotion/styled > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
20:42:49.185    warning "@emotion/styled > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.12.13" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
20:42:49.193    warning " > @graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo@2.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "graphql-tag@^2.0.0".
20:42:58.177    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
20:43:00.569    Done in 26.87s.
20:43:00.598    Detected Next.js version: 10.0.6
20:43:00.781    Running "yarn build"
20:43:01.046    yarn run v1.22.10
20:43:01.069    $ next build
20:43:01.617    info  - Creating an optimized production build...
20:43:01.633    Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
20:43:01.633    This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
20:43:01.633    You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
20:43:01.633    https://nextjs.org/telemetry
20:43:01.874    We detected TypeScript in your project and reconfigured your tsconfig.json file for you.
20:43:01.874    The following suggested values were added to your tsconfig.json. These values can be changed to fit your project's needs:
20:43:01.874        - exclude was set to ['node_modules']
20:43:07.311    Failed to compile.
20:43:07.311    ./src/components/InputField.tsx:2:23
20:43:07.311    Type error: Cannot find module 'Formik' or its corresponding type declarations.
20:43:07.311      1 | import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
20:43:07.311    > 2 | import { Field } from "Formik";
20:43:07.311        |                       ^
20:43:07.311      4 | import {
20:43:07.311      5 |     FormControl,
20:43:07.336    error Command failed with exit code 1.
20:43:07.336    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
20:43:07.360    Error: Command "yarn build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was the import from Formik statement

```
import { Field } from "Formik";
```

needed to be

```
import { Field } from "formik";
```

On my machine (Windows) it builds fine. Because of the different OS or settings, Vercel was failing in the build step and expects the "f" in "formik" to be lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

Similar what happened to OP my project was failing because of a folder I renamed, my code was working fine on local but was failing on vercel. I found [this message](https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-module-not-found-error) from vercel:

> One possible cause for this issue is the fact that some filesystems are case-insensitive, however Vercel deployments use a case-sensitive filesystem. Because of this, it is possible that when you change the letter-casing in filenames on your local machine, Git will only pick up changes in your respective static import statements. This would mean that your repository is now syntactically incorrect, resulting in a build error when deploying the repository on the Vercel platform.

And the suggested solution (that worked for me is) is to make sure that your letter-casing in your filenames and imports are identical between your repository and local machine with this command:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```