# Bug? Vercel says import error but local works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, vercel, sveltekit

[Github Link](https://github.com/jardo5/PortfolioSiteV3)

I'm trying to host my SvelteKit portfolio site to Vercel, yet it keeps throwing me the error

> RollupError: Could not resolve "../../utilities/isLoggedIn" from "src/routes/admin/+page.svelte"

When I run npm run build locally I have no issues. I've tried 28 different ways of doing it (yes I counted my commits) and nothing works I'm all out of options. Either I'm missing something completely or Vercel has a problem with me. (I've tried both CLI Vercel & Web vercel if that makes a difference). I've also checked for capitals and misspellings. Highly frustrating.

Comment: If you think it is a bug with Vercel and not your code, then you might want to contact their customer support.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix from the Vercel team.

> [One possible cause for this issue is the fact that some filesystems are case-insensitive, however Vercel deployments use a case-sensitive filesystem. Because of this, it is possible that when you change the letter-casing in filenames on your local machine, Git will only pick up changes in your respective static import statements. This would mean that your repository is now syntactically incorrect, resulting in a build error when deploying the repository on the Vercel platform.](https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-module-not-found-error)

TLDR: git config core.ignorecase false

Similar post on SO with same answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172043/vercel-cli-build-fails-with-error-type-error-cannot-find-module-formik-or-it?rq=2)